# Block mode for command history of python interpreter under Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

The interpreter command history in both `python.el` (Emacs 23) and `python-mode.el` recall previous code bodies one line at a time (when pressing <kbd>M-p</kbd>).

Block recall, such as is used in IPython, IDLE, and Emacs SLIME (Common Lisp), is nicer for revising functions.

Is there a way to get block recall in one of the inferior modes for Python in Emacs?

**EDIT**:

To be specific, if I enter

```
>>> def afunc(x):
...     print x
... 
>>>
```

and then press <kbd>M-p</kbd>, I get

```
>>>     print x
```

instead of the whole function.

Comment: Can't reproduce for both modes. M-p brings back the block - if previously inserted. Please send an example which would fail.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Does that work for you out of the box (say, with `emacs -Q`? It doesn't for me.

Comment: @danlei Yes - just checked again with GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.25) of 2015-10-28

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Ok, thanks. I guess it's time for an update then. (Still on 24.3.1 on this machine.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `C-j` instead of `RET` when entering your code, and it will work. It's not *exactly* what you ask for, but it doesn't really make a big difference in practice.